# Provide documentation for API methods exposed through Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How can I document each cloud endpoints APIs? For example I have the following code. I can write an overview for `FooApi` with `@Api` annotation. However I want to write a doc for the method `getSomething` here. Is there any annotation?

```
@Api(name = "foo", version = "v1", description = "this api...")
public class FooApi {
  // I want to write a description for this specific method
  @ApiMethod(httpMethod = "get")
  public Bar getSomething() {
  }
}
```

Comment: There's always javadoc, but for a start the api explorer `/_ah/api/explorer` can help. Since that basically just shows the discovery document you might be able to extract something useful from there.

Comment: I want to write docs for `/_ah/api/explorer`. The description from `@Api` appears in `/_ah/api/explorer` correctly. What I want to accomplish here is to write descriptions for methods and make them appear in `/_ah/api/explorer`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadoc for `@ApiMethod` annotations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiMethod) and [Endpoints Annotations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#attributes_1) article, there are no attributes yet implemented for `@ApiMethod` to display as `description` like that of the `@Api` annotation. For reference the `@Api` annotation attributes that are supported can be also be found in the same [Endpoints Annotations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#attributes) article and the [`@Api` annotation Javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/Api).